# Resource Type is different with apex return type?

Tags: visual-workflow

Hi have created flow with apex class, apex returning list of string but in flow action i can see only single variable resources. Please suggest me why i am not able to select list of variable resource in apex flow action.

```
public static List<Integer> diff(List<DateTime> ids){
    
    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT id FROM BusinessHours LIMIT 1];
    List<Integer> listofRemainingHours = new List<Integer>();
    Datetime cDT = System.now();
        for(DateTime targetid : ids){
        Long milliseconds = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, targetid , cDT);
        Integer remainingHours = milliseconds.intValue();
        listofRemainingHours.add(remainingHours);
    }  
   
   return listofRemainingHours;
```

}

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide help. [Edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Added code please check and help me to solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because flows are [bulkified](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5), which means Invocable Actions receive a list of elements so they can be processed as if they were being processed in parallel. To map to a Collection, you need to make it a nested list.

```
// This maps to a single input/output variable
@InvocableMethod public static String[] toUppercase(String[] inputs) {
  String[] outputs = new String[0];
  for(String input: inputs) {
    outputs.add(input?.toUppercase());
  }
  return outputs;
}
```

```
// This method would map to Collection variables
@InvocableMethod public static List<String[]> toUppercase(List<String[]> inputs) {
  List<String[]> outputs = new List<String[]>();
  for(String[] inputList: inputs) {
    String[] outputList = new String[0];
    for(String input: inputList) {
      outputList.add(input?.toUppercase());
    }
    outputs.add(outputList);
  }
  return outputs;
}
```